# Fit text exactly without spacing

Tags: html, css, typography

In CSS/HTML, using a simple text within a div with no margin/padding with a given font-size (assume 36px) and a given line-height of 36px will not fit exactly, there's always some spacing at the top of the line. Reducing the line-height for 20% (i.e. in this case 29.8) seems the result in the desired effect.

Why is this, is there any browser thing I am missing? I'd assume having a line-height equal to font-size should actually NOT add any spacing around a line at all?

Update: The effect I am actually getting is called "half-leading". Howevever, I assumed that when setting the line-height equal to the font-size, no leading may occur at all as the browsers' calculated half leading should result in 0px.

Update 2: Just found this in the CSS-Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height
However, I am still confused considering how to avoid having added ascender/descender at all?

Comment: is not it a gap needed?, so letters from a line doesn't lay over other line ?

Comment: Because line height **includes** spacing around the letter glyphs so they don't touch.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense for me .. I assumed to specified to avoid any kind of leading or half-leading around text yet it is still there?

Comment: hmmm , room is preserved for top of capital letters or numbers and for bottom of letters like : jpqy  play with : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbrti

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your update #2:

Since ascender/descender height is calculated for each font, there are fonts that don't have ascenders/descenders, like all caps monospace. It would need to be a font that doesn't include any characters with a/d; just applying text-transform: capitalize wouldn't work.

A roundabout solution, but as you've stated it is a "feature not a bug".